# linux "hdparm -B" what is a good power management value?

Tags: electrical-power, hdparm, media-server

I run a home server with Linux (ubuntu). Data (not the os, not swap, not /home) is stored on a large software RAID5 array.

The server is on 24/7, but to reduce noise I would like the raid drives to spin down automatically after about 10 minutes when they are not accessed.

I've set this with "hdparm -S" for the drives in question, but it will only work if I also set the power management via "hdparm -B" to a value below 128 (default is 254).

Since documentation is pretty slim on the topic: what value would you recommend for a reasonable compromise to achieve a quiet environment, but not increase the strain on the drives extraordinarily?

I can hear the spindle motor, but I don't think it will get any quieter if the heads are parked after each access...

The machine uses 3 WD20NPVT drives (Western Digital 2.5"). I know these are not designed for always-on servers. I can live with that.

I do not really care about power consumption. Performance is also not an issue, this machine streams mp3 files to a maximum of 2 clients for a few hours a day. If it takes 90 seconds for the drives to spin up before the music starts that's fine...

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Unfortunately, home servers are one thing that we really don't do here. You may wish to visit our sister sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) and [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and read their respective FAQ entries to determine if your question would be on topic at one or both of those sites.

Comment: Why aren't the drives already spinning down?  Are you certain there are no reads/writes happening on that filesystem keeping the drives awake?  Why not just pick a value and try it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you set the value to 254 if donnt want to hear that sound. 
I think the hard driver is one of the "C1 issue" WD/HT Drivers.
Also i have the same issue hdd of Hitachi.
You can google "WD C1 issue" for more information about your HDD!